# What is the Seal God places on the foreheads of the 144,000 in Revelation 7? Sealed by the Holy Spirit or the word Emet (Truth)?

Tags: john, revelation

I am trying to determine exactly what the Seal placed on the 144,000 by God was. I have heard two directions and I want to see what everyone else might say. The word Truth or Emet would be in John's style, but others assume the Holy Spirit is correct based on Ephesians 1:13-14!

Answer (score 0):

In my book I go with the "Holy Spirit" answer, partly because Ephesians is not the only source. There is also "It is God who establishes us with you in Christ and has commissioned us; he has put his seal upon us and given us his Spirit in our hearts as a guarantee" (2 Corinthians ch1 vv21-22, RSV), echoing the words of the Ephesians ch1 vv13-14 reference. The "guarantee is these verses is being given to us, assuring us of the faithfulness of God's promise.

In the event of ch7, we are surely meant to see an analogy with the "sealing" of Ezekiel ch9 v4, which identifies those who still belong to God and protects them from the judgement being given on the rest of Jerusalem. And also with the blood-anointing of Exodus ch12 vv21-23, which identified the nation belonging to God and protected them from the judgement being given on the Egyptians.

In Revelation ch9 v4, the seal of God has a protective effect against what I take to be spiritual warfare- specifically, the impact on the world of faith-destroying Despair (the argument on this point is too long to be included here).

Therefore I take the "seal" to be the Holy Spirit which identifies the saints as belonging to God, the counterpart of the "mark" which identifies those who belong to the beast.

Answer (score 0):

There are two sets of 144,000 in Revelation 7 and 14. If they were the same people, than the seal should be the name of Jesus and His Father. Revelation 14:1 read;

> Then I looked, and there before me was the Lamb, standing on Mount Zion, and with him 144,000 **who had his name and his Father’s name written on their foreheads.** (NIV)

The next question is, are they the same people? For in Revelation 7, it explicitly are Jews, unlike those in Revelation 14. Let us read again who are in Revelation 7. Twelve tribes of Jews are listed.

1 - Judah    - the 4th son  - meaning "I will praise the Lord" (Gen 29:35)

2 - Reuben   - the 1st son  - meaning "The Lord has looked on me" (Gen 29:32)

3 - Gad      - the 7th son  - meaning "good fortune" (Gen 30:11)

4 - Asher    - the 8th son  - meaning "How happy I am" (Gen 30:13)

5 - Naphtali - the 6th son  - meaning "won a great struggle" (Gen 30:8)

6 - Manasseh - Joseph son   - meaning "make me to forget" (Gen 41:51)

7 - Simeon   - the 2nd son  - meaning "the Lord heard me" (Gen 29:33)

8 - Levi     - the 3rd son  - meaning "attached to me" (Gen 29:34)

9 - Issachar - the 9th son  - meaning "reward me" (Gen 30:18)

10- Zebulun  - the 10th son - meaning "honor" (Gen 30:20)

11- Joseph   - the 11th son - meaning "taken away my disgrace, may he add" (Gen 30:23)

12- Benjamin - the 12th son - meaning "son of my right hand" (Gen 35:18)

Review the list, if said it is literally the 12 tribes of Israel, they are not exactly, neither follow the order nor the names. It is obviously missing Dan and has Manasseh replaced, but without Ephraim. However if we look closely to the meaning of the names, we will find they combined to form a message of the Gospel.

> I will praise the Lord for He has looked on me and give me good fortune. How happy I am, because I won a great struggle, God is making me to forget. God hears me and is attached to me. He reward me with honor and take away my disgrace, and may He add to me the son of His right hand.

As such, both 144,000 in Revelation 7 & 14 are the same, and the seal should be the name of Jesus and His Father.

Comment: Comparing with the lists of tribes by territory (e.g. in Joshua), two names known for idolatry (Ephraim and Dan) are missing. They have been replaced by the names of Joseph and Levi, both famous for their faithfulness.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I have found, looking at some other texts that the name, "Emet" Hebrew for Truth will be written on the foreheads of both groups, and the names of God and Y'shua are translated to mean the same thing at that time.

Comment: @StephenDisraeli - Ephraim and Manasseh were only sons of Joseph. Replaced Ephraim by Joseph left only the Manasseh descendants, making the list has double Manasseh. Note Jacob put his right hand on Ephraim (Gen 48:14).

Answer (score 0):

Only the New Testament discusses the Seal of God.  Literal seals were made of wax and impressed with a unique image to certify ownership, authority or origin.  They were used on letters and legal documents and also on objects such as the tomb of Jesus (Matt 27:66) to prevent unauthorized interference or tampering with the contents.

When applied to people, the same concept applied – the seal of God was used to certify ownership

- 2 Tim 2:19 - Nevertheless, the firm foundation of God stands, having this **seal**: "The Lord knows those being His," and, "Let everyone naming the name of the Lord depart from iniquity."

Paul suggests that circumcision used to act as God’s seal (Rom 4:11).  Seal or sealing is used to describe the gift of the Holy Spirit:

- 2 Cor 1:22 - the One also having **sealed** us and having given the pledge of the Spirit in our hearts.
- Eph 1:13, 14 - And in Him, having heard and believed the word of truth—the gospel of your salvation—you were **sealed with the promised Holy Spirit**, who is the pledge of our inheritance until the redemption of those who are God’s possession, to the praise of His glory.
- Eph 4:30 - And do not grieve the Holy Spirit of God, in whom you were **sealed** for the day of redemption.
- John 6:27 - Do not work for the food that is perishing, but for the food enduring unto eternal life, which the Son of Man will give to you; for God the Father has sealed Him."

Thus, when we seek the bread of life that endures to eternal life (John 6:27).  By this gift we, in turn, also certify that God is true (John 3:33).

This, God’s seal of the Holy Spirit signifies a complete change of life beginning at conversion which should be conspicuous as a Godly life to those around us.

This idea is used frequently in the book of Revelation (Rev 5 – 9) and also denotes the protection enjoyed by God’s faithful people:

- Rev 7:2, 3 - And I saw another angel ascending from the east, with the **seal of the living God**. And he called out in a loud voice to the four angels who had been given power to harm the land and the sea: “Do not harm the land or sea or trees **until we have sealed the foreheads** of the servants of our God.”
- Rev 9:3, 4 - And out of the smoke, locusts descended on the earth, and they were given power like that of the scorpions of the earth. They were told not to harm the grass of the earth or any plant or tree, but only those **who did not have the seal** of God on their foreheads.
- Rev 14:1 - Then I looked and saw the Lamb standing on Mount Zion, and with Him 144,000 who had **His name and His Father’s name written on their foreheads**.

Thus, God’s people are miraculously preserved who have the seal of God, the Holy Spirit, which denotes the Name of the Lamb and the Father written on the forehead (Rev 14:2; compare Ex 13:9, 28:38, Eze 9:4).

[NOTE: If one wish to make a connection between "Emet" (= Hebrew word for "truth") and the seal of God, then that would be a stretch - I could find no explicit connection between *Emet*/truth and *Seal* in the Hebrew OT - "seal of God" only occurs in the NT.  Nevertheless, one might make a NT case for the seal being the truth that we are sealed by the Holy Spirit for God's service??]

Comment: See Ezekiel' vision in Ezekiel 9, for another seal. The seal of "Tav."

Comment: @Michael - I referenced that already in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note that they are sealed ‘in’, not ‘on’ their foreheads.  Reading this verse with the obvious definition of ‘receiving’ given in Romans 15:28, it appears that the 144k Jews have received Christ as their messiah. This is a change from what Paul tells us in Romans 11:7 that the Jews have been blinded. Likewise when the false prophet institutes the mark of the beast, mimicking the seal of God, its recipients will be true believers that the Antichrist is the messiah, or in kind to the Jewish church receiving an offering in their hands, those who do not really believe may be bribed to act like it.

Revelation 7:3
“Saying, Hurt not the earth, neither the sea, nor the trees, till we have sealed the servants of our God in their foreheads.”

Romans 15:28
“When therefore I have performed this, and have sealed to them this fruit, I will come by you into Spain.”

Romans 11:7
“What then? Israel hath not obtained that which he seeketh for; but the election hath obtained it, and the rest were blinded”

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the answers. I have found, looking at some other texts that the name, "Emet" Hebrew for Truth will be written on the foreheads of both groups, and the names of the Lamb and His Father (Rev. 14:1-my Greek New Testament) are translated to mean the same thing (Truth) at that time. So with the answers here and the other results of my research, it appears Emet/Truth, AKA the Lamb's (Y'shua)name and that of(God) His Father is overwhelming to be the Mark placed on the foreheads of both groups of 144,000! So, thank you for your input. It is much appreciated!

Comment: This answer claims to have the definitive answer to this question, but doesn't provide any references, making it useless to anyone else that wants to know the answer.  It claims to be the result of research, but none of that research is shown.